# c# ms-word office-interop problem with FindAndReplace Header

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I´m trying to FindAndReplace a Header of a document with Word.Interop in c#, but it doesn´t find the text, However when i do it for the footer it works fine. I don´t know what the problem is. My code is:

```
private void FindAndReplaceFooter(Word.Document aDoc,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2; // 2 replace all the occurrence, 0 replace none, 1 replace first
        object wrap = 1;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in aDoc.Sections)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footerRange = section.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;

            footerRange.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike, ref nmatchAllForms, 
                ref forward, ref wrap, ref format,  ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);


            if (footerRange.Find.Found)
            {

                Logger.Trace(Logger.GetCallerInfo(), this, "Encuentra Footer  {0}:", replaceWithText);
            }
        }
```

And the code for the Header is :

```
   object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2; // 2 replace all the occurrence, 0 replace none, 1 replace first
        object wrap = 1;


        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section Wordsection in aDoc.Sections)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerrRange = Wordsection.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            // headerrRange.Select();

            headerrRange.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike, ref nmatchAllForms,
                ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);




            if (headerrRange.Find.Found)
            {

                Logger.Trace(Logger.GetCallerInfo(), this, "Encuentra Header  {0}:", replaceWithText);
            }
        }
```

I don´t know what i´m doing wrong. Thank u very much.
Best regards,

Jorge Alonso.

Comment: I'm assuming you've checked that the search term is definitely in the *primary* Header (not first page header). You're specifying `MatchCase = true` : Are you sure the case of the search term is the same as in the Header? Same question concerning `MatchWholeWord`...

Comment: As an aside... On the assumption you're running both sets of code in your solution, why would you `foreach` through all the sections twice? That's not as efficient as looping the sections once and performing both sets of Find/Replace in the same loop. No need to answer that, just felt I should point it out...

Comment: My header is in all the pages of the document.I´m sure the case of the search term is the sames as in the Header. In Fact, I have FindAndReplace por the same text for the document and it works. I have a footer and in the footer works fine.

Comment: I believe you, that it works otherwise, which is why I asked you to double-check those things... The only difference I see in the code is a different object name for the Section: `Wordsection in aDoc.Sections` which shouldn't be an issue. Ah! Is the text in the header in a text box or some other kind of "container"?

Comment: I solved it. it works fine. the problem was in the word template i created, so i create a new template and it works. Than u @cindy-meister